# throttle bandwith to API like twitter does

Tags: apache-2.2, rate-limiting

lookikng to  limit the number of api requests from clients. wondering if there is a way to do it with apache or do i have to write some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't do it in apache..  I'd do it at network layer with iptables.

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set`

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 86400 --hitcount 100 -j REJECT`

Change 86400 to the number of seconds you want to keep the block for (86400 is 1 day), and 100, is the hit count, how many you're prepared to allow per IP.

You can also change -j REJECT to -j DROP, which defines the packet behavior when the condition is met.  DROP seamlessly drops packets, and REJECT returns a "port unreachable" or similar error.

That said, there was a mod_throttle that would do something similar, but I can't seem to find much information about it.  I think it feels neater to do this kind of thing at the network/kernel level, rather than in apache.  Apache is good at serving requests.  Let it do what it does best, and don't burden it with having to track connections too.

(yes, I did just copy my answer to a previous question..)

Comment: This is an IP-based solution, as far as I can see. But Twitter API limits are based in the client credentials. There's a way to do this at IP tables level?

Comment: I have no idea.  Possibly, but you'd need to have some way to inspect the HTTP session.  There *are* L7 devices/technologies that can do it.